# How do I put a dictionary in the datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, dictionary, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a good way to store a Python dictionary in the datastore?  I want to do something like the following:

```
from google.appengine.ext import db

class Recipe(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  style = db.StringProperty()
  yeast = db.StringProperty()
  hops = db.ListofDictionariesProperty()
```

Of course, that last line doesn't actually work.  I need hops to be a list of key-value pairs, where the key is always a string and the value can be a string, int, or float, but I can't see anything in that would allow me to do that in the [Property classes](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Serializing a dict with `repr` is a good way to do it.  You can then reconstitute it with `eval`, or if you don't trust the data, a "[safe eval](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496746/)".

An advantage of repr over pickling is that the data is readable in the database, even queryable in desperate cases.

Comment: JSON is generally safer than eval.

Comment: I probably won't need to query that field, but I like that I have the option.  Also, correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't using repr and using JSON have the same output in this case?

Comment: Even with "safe eval," `repr` could be dangerous.  Guido himself doubts that you could write such a function.  See http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=671.  JSON is simpler than python, and I have more confidence that a JSON parser wouldn't be vulnerable in the way that `eval` can be.

Comment: JSON is the better solution here, but for the record, you can write a safe eval that will deserialize dicts of primitive values safely.

Comment: JSON requires some overhead for some properties. For example, you can't simply use JSON to serialize the DateTimeProperty values.

Answer (score 7):

You can use json

Comment: @gnibbler: Convert the `dict` into JSON format and store it as a `db.StringProperty`?

Comment: @Kit, yes. Apart from being a safer than repr/eval and saving you writing a "safe eval", JSON is more portable should you find yourself using a different language at some stage

Answer (score 2):

You could [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) the dictionary and store it as a StringProperty.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure there's no way to store a Python dictionary. But why not just place what you'd like in hops as a second model?

Also, as mentioned by John you could use pickle, but (and correct me if I'm wrong) store it as a [Blob](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#Blob) value instead.

Comment: @Bartek, you can use the dumps and loads functions of the pickle module to work with strings:
>>>cPickle.loads(cPickle.dumps({1:"one"}))
{1: 'one'}

Answer (score 1):

Your options are basically to use pickle, to use a db.Expando and make each key in the dict a separate property, or to have a StringListProperty of keys and one of values and zip() them back to a dict when reading.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [JsonProperty](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference#Python_Properties_and_value_types).
Value is a Python object (such as a list or a dict or a string) that is serializable using Python's json module; Cloud Datastore stores the JSON serialization as a blob. Unindexed by default.
Optional keyword argument: compressed.

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Article(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    stars = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    tags = ndb.StringProperty(repeated=True)
    info = ndb.JsonProperty()
```

Comment: I'm surprised this isn't higher. I'm pretty sure JsonProperty is exactly what someone in the position of OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
class MyEntity(db.Model):
    dictionary_string = db.StringProperty()

payload = {{}...{}}

# Store dict
my_entity = MyEntity(key_name=your_key_here)
my_entity.dictionary_string = str(payload)
my_entity.put()

# Get dict
import ast
my_entity_k = db.Key.from_path('MyEntity', your_key_here)
my_entity = db.get(my_entity_k)
payload = ast.literal_eval(my_entity.dictionary_string)
```